# Get typoscript values in extbase framework

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase

I am new to extbase(MVC) Framework , How can we get typoscript values in our extension :

Eg : suppose if i have some typoscript values like:

```
plugin.tx_some-extname.somevlaueX = XXXX
plugin.tx_some-extname.somevlaueY = yyyy
plugin.tx_some-extname.somevlaueZ = zzzz
```

how will i get these values in a specific action of our controller .I hope this makes sense ??

Comment: After searching a lot i guess, I got my answer [Configuration_EXTBASE](http://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3v4-mvc/wiki/ConfigurationManager_rework) . I haven't tried this, Will update this after testing the same in my extbase extension . Tx_Extbase_Configuration_ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FRAMEWORK:***SOME CONFIGURARION TYPE ***

Comment: Redundant effort, check my answer for common solution

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Declare values in the `settings` scope (in the setup field) ie:

```
plugin.tx_some-extname.settings {
    myXsetting = XXXX
}
```

So the all `settings` will be accesible in your plugin in `$this->settings` (as `array`) :

```
$valX = $this->settings['myXsetting'];
```

Comment: thanks for this quick help: i will try this and will post my outcome here .

Comment: @bieser: This is working :) Once again thanks for the quick help

Answer (score 1):

In TYPO3-7.6 + the whole TypoScript for an extension can be retrieved with

```
$typoScript = $this->configurationManager->getConfiguration( $this->configurationManager::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FRAMEWORK);
```

where for the 1st parameter exist 3 different options:

```
$this->configurationManager::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_SETTINGS
$this->configurationManager::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FRAMEWORK
$this->configurationManager::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FULL_TYPOSCRIPT
```

optional for the function `$this->configurationManager->getConfiguration()` the extension-key can be given as 2nd parameter and the plugin-name as 3rd parameter. So the whole command looks like this:

```
$typoScript = $this->configurationManager->getConfiguration( $this->configurationManager::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FRAMEWORK, $extensionKey,  $pluginName );
```

Consider that the static template has to be included in the backend-template to return the desired output.

ConfigurationManager is an instance of
`TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManager`